# frequency and Period what is the role of division in these problems

Tags: trigonometry

Is this a close definition for period for a sine or cosine function?

The equation for a cosine or sine wave period is

$period=\frac{2\pi}{b}$

If b= $2\pi$ then; period = 1;  example. $\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}=1$

If b>$2\pi$ then; period<1;  example. $\frac{2 \pi}{3\pi}=\frac23$

If b<$2\pi$ then, period>1;  example. $\frac{2 \pi}{\pi}=2$

It is a simple question that I am trying to figure out.  I am still wondering how a cosine or sine wave can repeat itself without having to travel the circumference of the circle?

Here are some pictures of what I am working on.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to travel around a 2D circle. *Projection* on x-axis is a 1-dimensional representation, it is given by

$$ f(x) = A \sin [ 2 \pi \left(\frac{ x - x1}{b}\right)] +d $$

Wave length $b$, amplitude $A$, phase difference $~=\dfrac{x1}{b},~d$ is shift up of entire sine curve above x-axis.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out.  period= 2 pi/b.    We are answering the question; How many times does b fit into 2 pi radian.  Frequency = 1/period.  We are seeing how many times the period fits into 1 radian.